# <debug target crashed> error when selecting date in <input type='date'>

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following simple .dart and .html files

**.dart**

```dart
//import 'dart:html';

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

/// A Polymer `<main-app>` element.
@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  @observable DateTime today = new DateTime.now();
  @observable String aDate = '';

  /// Constructor used to create instance of MainApp.
  MainApp.created() : super.created();


  void onChangeFired() {
    print(aDate);
  }
}
```

**.html**

```dart
<!-- import polymer-element's definition -->
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">

<polymer-element name="main-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <input type='date' value='{{aDate}}'
     on-change='{{onChangeFired}}' id='time' class='margin-lb5px'>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="main_app.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Running the app in Dartium displays the calendar dropdown. However, each time I select a date, the application crasshes (exits) after printing the selected date with the following

```dart
2005-02-08 (:1)
<debug target crashed>
```

Nothing else is displyed in the console.

I created a new new polymer-app using Stagehand with the same result. Nothing else is there in the application.

This problem is present in the last two Dart Dev updates - I am currently using Dart 1.9.0-dev.9.1 (rev 44018) with the same result.

I am using the Dart eclipse plugin on Windows 8.1

Thanks

Comment: File a bug report. http://dartbug.com/

Comment: I can reproduce this with just `<input type="date">` in index.html. Definitely a bug in Dartium. I filed http://dartbug.com/22609

Comment: Great. I thought it was broken.

Comment: The bug has returned in Dart 1.10.0-dev.1.1 (rev 45089). Looking forward to the fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in the Chrome version Dartium is built on.
Hopefully with Dart 1.15 we get the updated Dartium where this issue should be fixed.