# Error binding date input field with Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Just upgraded to Dart SDK version 1.10.0 on Windows 8 platform. Generated sample polymer app. Added following line to main_app.html:

```
<input type="date" value="{{dob}}"/>
```

and following line to main_app.dart:

```
 @observable String dob = '';
```

Code generates following error:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
https://ssl.gstatic.com/chrome/components/doodle-notifier-01.html
Observatory listening at http://127.0.0.1:50511/

Complete app is as follows:
main_app.dart:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_input.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
/// A Polymer `<main-app>` element.
@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
  @observable String reversed = ''; 

  @observable String dob = '';   //added this line

  /// Constructor used to create instance of MainApp.
  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  void reverseText(Event event, Object object, PaperInput target) {
   reversed = target.value.split('').reversed.join('');
  }
}
```

main_app.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">
<polymer-element name="main-app">
  <template>
   <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
   </style>
   <paper-input label="Type something..." on-keyup="{{reverseText}}">
   </paper-input>
   <p>
       Reversed: {{ reversed }}
   </p>
   <input type="date" value="{{dob}}"/> 
 </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="main_app.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: setting date works. @observable String dob = '2015-05-13'; shows date in date field. I can enter new date manually or use up/down arrow to change date but click on the right arrow to display month and days and select date   then program crashes.

Comment: Seems similar to http://dartbug.com/22609 (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777278) which was fixed recently.